# MongoDB/PHP set type map independently on embedded documents

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

I have had a good look around but I can't seem to find the answer to my question. If I have the following document with several different embedded document types, how do I set the type map for each document independently of the others?

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("bf98321fba31233"),
    name : "Example", 
    comments : [
         comment : { _id : ObjectId("bf98321fba31233"), text : "Example comment type" },
         comment : { _id : ObjectId("bf98321fba31233"), text : "Another example" }
    ],
    attachments : [
         attachment : { _id : ObjectId("bf98321fba31233"), url : "/var/www/blah/foo" },
         attachment : { _id : ObjectId("bf98321fba31233"), url : "/var/www/blah/bar" }
    ]
}
```

I know how I can set a type map for all embedded documents using the [PHP7 MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.settypemap.php):

```
$cursor = $mongo->executeQuery("TestDB.TestCollection", new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]));
$cursor->setTypeMap(['root' => 'RootObj', 'document' => 'SomeOtherObj']);
```

This will unserialize all of the embedded documents into instances of the SomeOtherObj class, and the root document into the RootObj class. What I really want to do is specify this for each type of embedded document.

```
$cursor->setTypeMap(['root' => 'RootObj', 'comment' => 'CommentObj', 'attachment' => 'AttachmentObj']);
```

Can it be done?

Comment: The functionality you're describing is not yet implemented. The related tracking ticket is [PHPC-314](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPC-314).

Comment: @jmikola thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a good read through and found a class I didn't know existed before, which allows MongoDB to remember which class each object belongs to without having to explicitly set a type map. I changed my class objects that implemented `MongoDB\BSON\Serializable` and `MongoDB\BSON\Unserializable` to just implementing `MongoDB\BSON\Persistable`.

`MongoDB\BSON\Persistable` injects a `__pclass` variable into the document, which is a reference to the class that was used during serialization. It uses that reference to decide which class to unserialize into and overrides the type map.

[`MongoDB\BSON\Persistable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-persistable.php)